# Are GPU limited devices such as Macbook Air a good source for wide market WebGL performance indicators?

Tags: typescript, webgl, pixi.js

Not happy with the title of the question, but we're working with PixiJS and WebGL on a web game. Game should run on pretty much all devices(WebGL capable ones at least) at reasonable framerate. We have an old Macbook Air at work where we test out performance and what impacts it. Our CPU time is usually at around 4ms and the device is heavily GPU limited. We've tried to run a simple shader for a simple grass effect, it just wobbles the picture trough a fragment shader. But the macbook did not like it, dropped the framerate immediately.

But the real question is, how realistic is it to use macbook air for general purpose performance benchmark? Even 5 years old phones have more capable GPU than macbook air and on those the performance is fine, but we don't know how to make sure we hit good performance for wide enough market and i am starting to think that macbook air is completely unrealistic and that phones have far more capable GPUs nowadays?

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform float customUniform;
uniform float loopLength; // The length of the looping interval

void main(void)
{
   vec2 uvs = vTextureCoord.xy;

   // Calculate the displacement factor based on the texture coordinates and time
   float displacement = sin((1.0 - uvs.y) * customUniform * 2.0 * 3.14159 / loopLength) * 0.05; // Adjust the magnitude of the wave effect

   // Apply the displacement to the texture coordinates
   uvs.x += displacement;

   // Sample the texture using the modified coordinates
   vec4 fg = texture2D(uSampler, uvs);

   gl_FragColor = fg;
}
```

This is the shader we've tested out. In itself is somewhat innocent. We were shocked to see such low performance on the Macbook Air. We do also test out our application on some phones and tablets.

Comment: "how realistic is it to use macbook air for general purpose performance benchmark" - that depends on your user base. If a lot of your users use such hardware, you should optimize for that. If not, skip it

Comment: We do not have such specific data, nor is it something we can google. Best case scenario is comparing the games from our competition but they also vary by a lot.

Comment: All you can  do is look at the general market share of MacOS, which is relatively low. The newer macbook air with the M1 or M2 chip have very good graphical performance. In your case I would make the use of shaders optional in a settings menu. Many mobile games do this "☑️ increase performance"

Comment: Sadly not an option. the game is a slots game. The grass in question is a symbol and they need to be always consistent in appearance. So it's one or the other.
Market share of MacOS is not that relevant because we're looking at lower end devices and their performance. We're searching for lowest performance out of 90% of all devices in use for example.

Comment: Do you even get hardware acceleration on the macbook? Sounds like you might be running swiftshader. That being said, someone in your team chose to benchmark using some old macbook air, if you want to know how that's a reasonable target, ask them, how would anyone on the internet not knowing any context be able to provide advice on that?

Comment: The only reason for macbook is its age and relatively low performance. I cannot simulate this kind of low performance. In the chrome web tools the lowest is "low end mobile" which is vague for a reason. 
We're not sure if it is a reasonable target.
I will check if it is even using hardware acceleration, did not think of that. Thank you